# create dynamic forms in java for web

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, user-interface, dynamic-forms, vaadin7

I wanted to create dynamic form based on some restful service,I know java pretty well but I lag in javascript and related framework,so I wanted to know is their any framework that will ease my task as simple as

```
Form form = new Form("form");
 form.add(new TextField("fullName", true));
 addControl(form);
 Checkbox married = new Checkbox("married", "Married?");
```

I found Apache click after googling,but it was last updated on 27 March 2011.

Any other similar framework with latest stable release ?

Comment: Did you look into GWT?

Comment: Is Vaadin suitable for this? GWT has bigger learning path I think.

Comment: I'm not sure about the longer learning curve but Vaadin is surely suitable; it uses GWT at it's core anyway.